# How to change the height of the Kinect mounted in turtlebot simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

(ROS - Electric; Ubuntu 11.10)

I am using Gazebo to simulate turtlebot.
How to change the height of the kinect mounted in turtlebot simulator. I need to increase the height of the kinect mount point in the turtlebot simulator so as to view the table tops of my environment. I am checking the turtlebot_description package which has the turtlebot.urdf.xacro file which loads all the meshes of the robot for the display. I have following questions

a) How to modify the urdf files to increase the height?

b) Does this change by itself change the height of the tf frame of the kinect so that i get the cloud from different height?

Any pointers/suggestions are appreciated!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39052/how-to-change-the-height-of-the-kinect-mounted-in-turtlebot-simulator/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could just change the "turtlebot_calib_cam_z" parameter in the [turtlebot_calibration.xacro](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot/file/e47d5a1dca1c/turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_calibration.xacro) file of turtlebot_description. If you installed from .debs you'll risk losing your changes on an update though, so the recommended way is to copy the parts you need to your own package and change them there.

The changes in your URDF will directly affect also the tf tree (because it is created based on the URDF model), so it should directly work.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-07-17**:
thanks Stefan.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In addition to Stefan's post, you might want to check out this video from ROSCon that talks about URDF. It's a great intro video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9WHxOpAUns

---

Originally posted by [dougbot01](https://answers.ros.org/users/2842/dougbot01/) with karma: 342 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-07-17**:
Thanks doughbot01 ... it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Indigo, you need to modify the following file or related file
/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_properties.urdf.xacro

You can find the following lines in the file:

If you want use a different sensor like asus_xtion_pro, you may directly modify the following file:
/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_description/urdf/sensors/asus_xtion_pro.urdf.xacro

---

Originally posted by [JollyGood](https://answers.ros.org/users/985/jollygood/) with karma: 58 on 2015-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1